# Recursive call to function giving error in XSLT

Tags: xslt, xslt-2.0

I am writing a function to split string without breaking word. For that i have return function which is doing recursive call to itself. It's giving me below error

1. When i am calling function with function prefix then getting error as "splitLine function under namespace http://whatever is not defined.".
2. When i am calling function without function prefix then getting Parse error in the function.

When i Try to use

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:splitLine($inString,$length - 1)"/>
```

in otherwise condition of function get function not defined error.

When i try to use without function prefix :

```
<xsl:value-of select="fn:splitLine($inString,$length - 1)"/>
```

I get parse error in Function.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://whatever">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" /> 
  <xsl:output method="xml" /> 
<xsl:function name="fn:splitLine" as="xs:string">
        <xsl:param name="inString" as="xs:string"/>
        <xsl:param name="length" as="xs:numeric"/>
        <xsl:variable name="delimiters"> ,."!?()</xsl:variable>
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="0.0 >= $length ">
                <xsl:value-of select="$inString"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$length >= string-length($inString)">
                <xsl:value-of select="$inString"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="contains($delimiters,substring($inString,$length + 1,1))">
                <xsl:value-of select="substring($inString,1,$length)"/>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:otherwise>
                <xsl:value-of select="fn:splitLine($inString,$length - 1)"/>
            </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:function>
<xsl:template match="/">
<xsl:value-of select="fn:splitLine('3 ZHANLANGUAN RD XICHENG, , , BEIJING, , CN, ',35)"/>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I am expecting output to be "3 ZHANLANGUAN RD XICHENG, , ," without breaking word.

Comment: Are you sure your processor supports XSLT 2.0?

Comment: What XSLT processor are you using? Your code works as expected under Saxon after adding a declaration for the "xs" (XML Schema) namespace.

Comment: Note also that the type `xs:numeric` is defined in XSLT 3.0 but not in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: Try adding `<xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:vendor')"/> - <xsl:value-of select="system-property('xsl:version')"/> ` to your XSLT to find out exactly what processor/version you are using.

Comment: Below is the result for the processor and Version : Processor : Oracle Corporation. : Version :2

Comment: @MichaelKay I tried it with xs:integer as well. Getting same result.

Comment: Following on from Michael Kay's answer, if you are unable to change the XSLT processor you use, you could just convert your XSLT from using a function to using a named template instead. See http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/bFWR5DT for example. This would work in XSLT 1.0 so should hopefully have fewer restrictions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Tim Thanks for the suggestion. Instead of using function , i Used named template and it worked perfectly fine :

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:fn="http://whatever">
  <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="no" /> 
  <xsl:output method="xml" />
  <xsl:template name="splitLine">
    <xsl:param name="inString"/>
    <xsl:param name="length"/>
    <xsl:variable name="delimiters"> ,."!?()</xsl:variable>
    <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="0.0 >= $length ">
            <xsl:value-of select="$inString"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$length >= string-length($inString)">
            <xsl:value-of select="$inString"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="contains($delimiters,substring($inString,$length + 1,1))">
            <xsl:value-of select="substring($inString,1,$length)"/>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:call-template name="splitLine">
                <xsl:with-param name="inString" select="$inString" />
                <xsl:with-param name="length" select="$length - 1" />
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:call-template name="splitLine">
        <xsl:with-param name="inString" select="'fullnameofsample supplier in the block" />
        <xsl:with-param name="length" select="35" />
    </xsl:call-template>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

This must be a quirk of your XSLT processor.
I checked your XSLT-2.0 file with `Saxon-HE 9.9.1.4J` and it works as expected after adding the following namespace to the `xsl:stylesheet` element:

```
xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
```

So, I guess, that your XSLT processor returned a different namespace as missing, because after adding the above one, all commands could be processed and the result is as expected.

Comment: I updated my template and re-tried, but i am getting same error "org.xml.sax.SAXException: splitLine function under namespace http://whatever is not defined."

Comment: I cannot reproduce your error. So, unfortunately, I am unable to help you any further.

Answer (score 0):

> Below is the result for the processor and Version : Processor : Oracle Corporation. : Version :2 –

Right. Oracle (before they acquired Sun) were well down the path to developing an XSLT 2.0 processor as part of the Oracle XDK (XML development kit). But they never really finished it, and it never achieved a high level of conformance with the spec.

It looks to me as if you have encountered a restriction in that processor - and I'm sure there are many others. I don't think many people are using the Oracle XDK these days, and I think it has had very little development since Oracle acquired Sun (and hence Java).